# Laravel Notification System

Tags: laravel, notifications, toastr

I use a simple Query Code to display Toastr in my application. This is the code:

```
 <script>
 document.getElementById("test").onclick = function() {
     $.toaster({
         priority : 'success',
         title : 'yassine Jennane',
         message : 'yassine jennane test toster'
     });
 };
 </script>
```

My problem is when there is another user connected in my application, he isn't receiving the notification at the same moment as the first one do. Why?

Link of the notification script + demo: [jQuery & Bootstrap Based Toast Notification Plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Bootstrap-Based-Toast-Notification-Plugin-toaster.html)

Comment: What do you mean by not receiving at the same moment as the first?

Comment: Where is your Laravel code for notification system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work like that. You need to create Event Classes and Broadcasting Channels. Further you need to have some socket.io node.js side so that the notifications are shown live on the client side.

You probably don't have experience in this subject, so I would suggest to do following things:

Have a look at following in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting

Watch following tutorial on laracasts: https://laracasts.com/series/real-time-laravel-with-socket-io/episodes/1

Of course you can have a look at some other tutorials you find on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you're using is a Jquery plugin that makes toasts in user browser, it works only for connected user, if you want to show notification for all the users using your application, you should use Cloud Messaging service, Firebase is good one.